# Need faster way to concatenate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have some big datafames from which I need to extract some colum/row combinations. I managed to do so with a couple of loops, knowing it will be very slow and I need to improve the speed a lot.

To explain the situation I prepared the following dataframe:

```
time = ['2020-02-01T00:00:00', '2020-02-01T00:05:00', '2020-02-01T00:10:00','2020-02-01T00:15:00', '2020-02-02T00:00:00', '2020-02-02T00:05:00', '2020-02-02T00:10:00','2020-02-02T00:15:00', '2020-02-03T00:00:00', '2020-02-03T00:05:00', '2020-02-03T00:10:00']

testframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['datetime', 'point1', 'point2', 'point3'])

testframe['datetime'] = time
testframe['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(testframe['datetime'])
testframe['point1'] = [1,1,1,np.nan,1,1,1,np.nan,1,1,1]
testframe['point2'] = [ np.nan, np.nan,2,2,2,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,2,2,2]
testframe['point3'] = [3,3,np.nan,3,3,3,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,2,2]
```

My goal is to have a dataframe like this:
[screenshot of final dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDqKL.png)

This is how I proceeded:

I want to group it by day, so I use

```
df_temp['classes'] = 'classname'

# create ID for each timeseries = 24 h
df_temp['id_day'] = df_temp.groupby(df_temp.datetime.dt.date).ngroup() + 1

#reorganize columns
cols = df_temp.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[-2:] + cols[:-2]
df_temp = df_temp[cols]
```

In the next step, I checked how many value (not NaN) exist per day (per id_day), because only days with a certain amount of values are interesting for me.
Therefore I used the following code:

```
# Calculate values per day for each datapoint in dataframe
val_per_day = pd.DataFrame(columns = df_temp.columns.tolist()).drop(['classes', 'datetime'], axis = 1)
for point in df_temp.columns.tolist()[3:]: # [3:0] start with id and include all other columns
    val_per_day[point] = df_temp[point].groupby(df_temp['id_day']).count()

val_per_day['id_day'] = val_per_day.index
val_per_day = val_per_day.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Which gives me a nice dataframe showing the `id_day, point1, point2, point3` and how many values these points contain per day. 
Up to here, everything is quite clear and runs fast enough.

Now I filtered this list, to find out which days have more values than a threshold.

```
# set threshold
threshold =3

days_above_threshold = pd.DataFrame(columns = val_per_day.columns.to_numpy(), index = [1])
list_of_days = []
relevant_points_dic = {}


for point in val_per_day.columns.to_numpy()[1:]:    # [1:], because 0 is column "id"

    list_temp = val_per_day['id_day'][val_per_day[point] >= threshold].to_numpy()

    if list_temp.size != 0:
        relevant_points_dic.update( {point : list_temp})
    else:
        None

relevant_days = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(relevant_points_dic, orient='index', dtype = 'int').transpose()
```

This gives me a dataframe with `point1, point2, point3` as columns and all the "relevant" days as values.

The next step is incredibly slow and can propably be improved:

I loop through all columns of the original dataframe, check if the id_day is relevant, and if so, I put the data into a temproray dataframe.
finally, I concat this temporary dataframe with the final dataframe (df). The code is the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
counter = 1
#print("Begin loading " + str(len(relevant_days.columns.to_numpy())) + " points ...")
for point in relevant_days.columns.to_numpy()[:]:

    df_new_temp = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['time', 'id_day', 'classes', 'name', 'value'])

    if (counter % 20 == 0):
        print("Loaded "+ str(counter) + " / " + str(len(relevant_days.columns.to_numpy())))
    counter += 1

    relevant_ids_raw =relevant_days[point].to_numpy()
    relevant_ids_nan = np.isnan(relevant_ids_raw)
    relevant_ids_not_nan =  ~ relevant_ids_nan
    relevant_ids = relevant_ids_raw[relevant_ids_not_nan]

    df_new_temp['id_day'] = df_temp.loc[df_temp['id_day'].isin(relevant_ids), 'id_day']
    df_new_temp['value'] = df_temp.loc[df_temp['id_day'].isin(relevant_ids), point]
    df_new_temp['classes'] = df_temp.loc[df_temp['id_day'].isin(relevant_ids), 'classes']
    df_new_temp['time'] = df_temp.loc[df_temp['id_day'].isin(relevant_ids), 'datetime']
    df_new_temp['name'] = point

    df = pd.concat([df, df_new_temp], ignore_index = True)
```

Checking it with line_profiler, I get the following log:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     5                                           def copy_data(df_temp, relevant_days):
     6                                           
     7         1        857.0    857.0      2.1      df = pd.DataFrame()
     8         1          1.0      1.0      0.0      counter = 1
     9         1        114.0    114.0      0.3      print("Begin loading " + str(len(relevant_days.columns.to_numpy())) + " points ...")
    10         4         19.0      4.8      0.0      for point in relevant_days.columns.to_numpy()[:]:
    11                                               
    12         3      15265.0   5088.3     38.1          df_new_temp = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['time', 'id_day', 'classes', 'name', 'value'])
    13                                           
    14         3          4.0      1.3      0.0          if (counter % 20 == 0):
    15                                                       print("Loaded "+ str(counter) + " / " + str(len(relevant_days.columns.to_numpy())))
    16         3          3.0      1.0      0.0          counter += 1
    17                                           
    18         3        136.0     45.3      0.3          relevant_ids_raw =relevant_days[point].to_numpy()
    19         3         14.0      4.7      0.0          relevant_ids_nan = np.isnan(relevant_ids_raw)
    20         3          6.0      2.0      0.0          relevant_ids_not_nan =  ~ relevant_ids_nan
    21         3         12.0      4.0      0.0          relevant_ids = relevant_ids_raw[relevant_ids_not_nan]
    22                                           
    23         3       7389.0   2463.0     18.4          df_new_temp['id_day'] = df_temp.loc[df_temp['id_day'].isin(relevant_ids), 'id_day']
    24         3       4589.0   1529.7     11.4          df_new_temp['value'] = df_temp.loc[df_temp['id_day'].isin(relevant_ids), point]
    25         3       3190.0   1063.3      8.0          df_new_temp['classes'] = df_temp.loc[df_temp['id_day'].isin(relevant_ids), 'classes']
    26         3       3978.0   1326.0      9.9          df_new_temp['time'] = df_temp.loc[df_temp['id_day'].isin(relevant_ids), 'datetime']
    27         3        656.0    218.7      1.6          df_new_temp['name'] = point
    28                                           
    29         3       3638.0   1212.7      9.1          df = pd.concat([df, df_new_temp], ignore_index = True)
    30                                           
    31                                           
    32         1        208.0    208.0      0.5      print("Finished loading data.")
    33         1          1.0      1.0      0.0      return df
```

What I have already tried:

- I've tried to somehow use .loc to add the data from the loop to the final dataframe. This didn't work for me, as in some loops I have more rows than in others which causes some pandas-index-trouble.
- I've tried to somehow put the data from the loop into a list and attach it all at once in the end. Again, it caused trouble with unequal sizes and as well, with many lists in lists that I couldn't deal with (might be lack of experience).

I have tried to explain my problem, if there are any questions I will try to answer them and I appreciate every hint on this case.
This code took some hours for just a fraction of work that has be done, so any speed up is welcomed!